# How to cluster dataset with more than 3 D and interet/Visualize?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Lets give an example
`X: 1 2 3 4 5
Y: .9 .91 .92 .93 .94
Z: 20 36 999 211
M. 4000 3456 1 0`

When I have such dataset, Which clustering algorithm to choose ? Also, How to interpret the results after clustering ?
Meaning: How to feed 4D dataset into cluster.

I found DBSCAN available on internet for 2D with which plot is possible. Since my dataset is 4 D and varies ILLOGICALLY...I am afraid to feed this to Algorithm

`

```
import pdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import square, sqrt
def regionQuery(P, eps, D): 
    neighbourPts = []
    for point in D:
        #print point        
        if sqrt(square(P[1] - point[1]) + square(P[2] - point[2]))<eps:
            neighbourPts.append(point)
    return neighbourPts
def DBSCAN(D, eps, MinPts):
    noise = []
    visited = []
    C = []
    c_n = -1
    for point in D:
        visited.append(point) #marking point as visited
    #   print point     
        neighbourPts = regionQuery(point, eps, D)
        if len(neighbourPts) < MinPts:
            noise.append(point)
        else:
            C.append([])            
            c_n+=1
            expandCluster(point, neighbourPts, C, c_n,eps, MinPts, D, visited)
    print("no. of clusters: " , len(C)  )
    print("length of noise:", len(noise))
    for cluster in C:
        col =[rand(1),rand(1),rand(1)]      
        #print(cluster)     
        plt.scatter([i[1] for i in cluster],[i[2] for i in cluster],color=col)
    plt.show()
def expandCluster(P, neighbourPts, C, c_n,eps, MinPts, D, visited):
    C[c_n].append(P)
    for point in neighbourPts:
        if point not in visited:
            visited.append(point) 
            neighbourPts_2 = regionQuery(point, eps, D)
            if len(neighbourPts_2) >= MinPts:
                neighbourPts += neighbourPts_2
        if point not in (i for i in C):
            C[c_n].append(point)
eps =20#input("enter eps")
x=200*rand(10)
y=200*rand(10)
l=[]
for i in range(10):
    l.append([i,x[i],y[i]])
#pdb.set_trace()
DBSCAN(l,eps,1)`
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python:

**Approach 1:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
import pandas as pd

y_test = [1, 0, 0]
y_pred = [1, 0, 0]
confusion_matrix=cm(y_test, y_pred)

list1 = ["Actual 0", "Actual 1"]
list2 = ["Predicted 0", "Predicted 1"]
pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix, list1,list2)
```

[image]

**Approach 2:**

While sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix provides a numeric matrix, you can generate a 'report' using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
y_true = pd.Series([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
y_pred = pd.Series([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2])

pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred, rownames=['True'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
```

which results in:

```
Predicted  0  1  2  All
True                   
0          3  0  0    3
1          0  1  2    3
2          2  1  3    6
All        5  2  5   12
```

This allows us to see that:

1. The diagonal elements show the number of correct classifications for each class: 3, 1 and 3 for the classes 0, 1 and 2.
2. The off-diagonal elements provides the misclassifications: for example, 2 of the class 2 were misclassified as 0, none of the class 0 were misclassified as 2, etc.
3. The total number of classifications for each class in both `y_true` and `y_pred`, from the "All" subtotals

This method also works for text labels, and for a large number of samples in  the dataset can be extended to provide percentage reports.